# Problem using Nonlinearfit on integral function

Tags: fitting

I tried to fit my data with a very complicate Integrated function. But I get many errors messages when I perform the fit. For exemple I get :

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand ....has evaluated to non-numerical
>   values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries
>   {{Infinity,1.}}.
>
> NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: The function value is not a list of real
>   numbers

I added `?NumericQ` to all of my function parameters (As explained in the forum) but still doesn't work...

I used `manipulate` to find the parameters approximatively too and fixe them in the fit function but still I get the same error message...

Here my code and function and data...

```
data={{0.01635, 31756.}, {0.01691, 29033.3}, {0.01747, 28584.5}, {0.01802, 
  27148.6}, {0.01857, 27560.3}, {0.01913, 26664.5}, {0.01969, 
  24857.8}, {0.02024, 24392.}, {0.02079, 23780.3}, {0.02135, 
  23624.6}, {0.02191, 22001.8}, {0.02246, 21508.1}, {0.02301, 
  21152.}, {0.02356, 20179.9}, {0.02412, 18917.1}, {0.02468, 
  19023.4}, {0.02523, 19312.2}, {0.02579, 17525.7}, {0.02634, 
  17125.}, {0.0269, 17610.7}, {0.02745, 16233.3}, {0.028, 
  15462.2}, {0.02856, 15606}, {0.02912, 15253.8}, {0.02967, 
  14715.7}, {0.03022, 13692.8}, {0.03079, 13733.5}, {0.03135, 
  13308.5}, {0.0319, 12976.1}, {0.03244, 12597.9}, {0.033, 
  12046.9}, {0.01442, 33274.2}, {0.01575, 30759.3}, {0.01712, 
  28168.1}, {0.01851, 26533.9}, {0.01992, 24367.4}, {0.02126, 
  23074.2}, {0.0226, 21306.2}, {0.024, 20009.5}, {0.02537, 
  17511.2}, {0.02674, 17062.3}, {0.02812, 15578.5}, {0.02949, 
  14643.2}, {0.03086, 13703.2}, {0.03223, 12567.1}, {0.03361, 
  11719.5}, {0.03499, 10743.7}, {0.03638, 9760.39}, {0.03776, 
  8954.93}, {0.03911, 8508.59}, {0.04049, 7881.02}, {0.04188, 
  7283.29}, {0.04326, 6963.29}, {0.04462, 6268.47}, {0.04598, 
  5997.21}, {0.04737, 5527.98}, {0.04874, 5185.51}, {0.0501, 
  4670.73}, {0.05148, 4431.54}, {0.05287, 4191.26}, {0.05425, 
  3834.45}, {0.0556, 3620.98}, {0.05697, 3376.51}, {0.05835, 
  3279.51}, {0.05974, 2999.57}, {0.06111, 2895.32}, {0.06248, 
  2674.02}, {0.06386, 2555.34}, {0.06524, 2392.53}, {0.06661, 
  2272.93}, {0.06797, 2095.73}, {0.06935, 1956.46}, {0.07073, 
  1842.65}, {0.0721, 1767.54}, {0.07346, 1672.86}, {0.07484, 
  1551.8}, {0.07623, 1442.5}, {0.07761, 1337.48}, {0.07897, 
  1349.77}, {0.08034, 1213.42}, {0.08165, 1191.64}, {0.05499, 
  3254.36}, {0.06006, 2610.76}, {0.0653, 2034.53}, {0.07064, 
  1620.34}, {0.07594, 1273.4}, {0.08103, 1037.84}, {0.0862, 
  846.835}, {0.09152, 663.821}, {0.0968, 546.384}, {0.10211, 
  450.586}, {0.10735, 361.546}, {0.11266, 306.515}, {0.11794, 
  248.237}, {0.12301, 207.235}, {0.12825, 178.407}, {0.13365, 
  153.417}, {0.13892, 129.051}, {0.14415, 118.376}, {0.14945, 
  102.996}, {0.15476, 93.4138}, {0.16002, 80.5334}, {0.16517, 
  70.9643}, {0.17038, 63.7196}, {0.17571, 61.1032}, {0.18097, 
  54.2794}, {0.18616, 47.2895}, {0.19145, 48.1226}, {0.19672, 
  44.8735}, {0.20194, 39.2719}, {0.20718, 37.0787}, {0.2124, 
  35.3538}, {0.21762, 32.7991}, {0.22286, 30.3889}, {0.22811, 
  30.4247}, {0.23332, 28.0626}, {0.23855, 26.2669}, {0.24382, 
  26.6999}, {0.24905, 26.7481}, {0.25423, 26.3765}, {0.25945, 
  26.0366}, {0.2647, 25.5727}, {0.26988, 23.2764}, {0.27511, 
  21.555}, {0.28031, 21.5483}, {0.28555, 21.747}, {0.29076, 
  20.7841}, {0.29604, 20.5216}, {0.30106, 18.8202}, {0.3058, 20.6229}}


mu0 = 4*Pi*10^(-7);
Ms = 0.0926/mu0 ;
bH = 2.91*10^8 ;
R = 4;

(*Function*)
Heff[q_, A_, Hi_] := (Hi/mu0 + 2*A/(Ms*mu0)*(q*10^(10))^2) 
p[q_, A_, Hi_] := Ms/Heff[q, A, Hi]
Vp[r_] := 4/3*Pi*(r*10^(-9))^3 
FF[q_, r_] := 9*SphericalBesselJ[1, q*10^(10)*r*10^(-9)]^2/(q*10^(10)*r*10^(-9))^2 
RH[q_, A_, Hi_] := (1/4)*p[q, A, Hi]^2*(2 + 1/(1 + p[q, A, Hi])^(0.5)) 
RM[q_, A_, Hi_] := ((1 + p[q, A, Hi])^(0.5) - 1)/2
Mz2[q_, dM_, r_] := ((dM/mu0)^2/(8*Pi)^3)*Vp[r]^2*FF[q, r];
h2[q_, Hp_, r_] := ((Hp/mu0)^2/(8^3*Pi^3))*Vp[r]^2*FF[q, r]; 

f[r_, c_, pp_] := (1/(c*r*10^(-9)*pp))*Exp[-(Log[r*10^(-9)] - Log[R*10^(-9)])^2/(2*pp^2)]

 Sigma1[q_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, Hi_?NumericQ, dM_?NumericQ, 
  Hp_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, pp_?NumericQ, R_?NumericQ, 
  BG_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[((Mz2[q, dM, r]*RM[q, A, Hi] + h2[q, Hp, r]*RH[q, A, Hi])*
     f[r, c, pp, R]), {r, 0, 100}, MaxRecursion -> 10] + BG


Manipulate[Plot[Sigma1[q, A, Hi, dM, Hp, c, pp, R, BG], {q, 0.001, 0.9}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0035], Red}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.005], Point[Log[data]]}, 
  ImageSize -> 850], {{A, 15*10^(-12)}, 0*10^(-12), 
  30*10^(-12)}, {{Hi, 20.65}, 0, 30}, {{dM, 0.05}, 0, 
  8000}, {{Hp, 0.05}, 0, 2}, {{c, 0.005*10^(9)}, 0*10^(9), 
  1*10^(9)}, {{pp, 0.78}, 0, 1}, {{R, 4}, 0, 5}, {{BG, 18}, 0, 30}]



    singlefit1 =  Normal[NonlinearModelFit[data, Sigma1[q, 15*10^(-12), 20.65, dM, Hp, c, pp, 4, 18], {{dM, 0.05}, {Hp, 0.062}, {c, 0.005*10^(-9)}, {pp,0.78}, {BG, 18}}, q]];
singlefit2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, Sigma1[q, 15*10^(-12), 20.65, dM, Hp, c, pp, 4, 18], {{Hi, 20.65}, {dM, 0.05}, {Hp, 0.062}, {c, 0.005*10^(-9)},{pp,0.78}, {BG, 18}}, q];

singlefit2["BestFitParameters"]
singlefit2["EstimatedVariance"]
singlefit2["ParameterErrors"]
singlefit2["ParameterConfidenceIntervals"]
MatrixForm[singlefit2["CorrelationMatrix"]]
Print[singlefit2["ParameterTable"]];
```

Comment: I think you need to modify the code to get the function `Sigma1` working first.  For example you define `p` as both a function and as a parameter.  (More minor is removing the lines `data = ReadList[file, Number, RecordLists -> True]; dataT = Transpose[data];
dataT = {dataT[[1]], dataT[[2]]};
data = Transpose[dataT];`)

Comment: I think that you might want to fit the log of the dependent variable but in the meantime here are a few specifics about the potential typos:  (1) `C` is a protected symbol.  Use lowercase letters for variable names.  (2) Change `p` when it is meant to be a parameter rather than a function to `pp`.  (3) Change `{C, 0.4*10^(-41), {p, 0.14}}` to `{c, 0.4*10^(-41), {pp, 0.14}` (besides changing `C` to `c` and `p` to `pp`, there is a `}` in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my code and use `manipulate` to find approximatively the parameters but then when I want to fit my function by fixing 2 or 3 parameters I still have the error message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find two mistakes in your code,

First, you defined "f[r_, c_, pp_]", and then in Next step, you are using it as  "f[r_, c_, pp_, R_]".

Second, In "NonlinearModelfit line", you are using value of BG twice.

In the Following I corrected your code and used "FindFit" :

```
 mu0 = 4*Pi*10^(-7);
 Ms = 0.0926/mu0;
 bH = 2.91*10^8;
 Heff[q_, A_, Hi_] := (Hi/mu0 + 2*A/(Ms*mu0)*(q*10^(10))^2)
 p[q_, A_, Hi_] := Ms/Heff[q, A, Hi]
 Vp[r_] := 4/3*Pi*(r*10^(-9))^3
 FF[q_, r_] := 9*SphericalBesselJ[1,q*10^(10)*r*10^(-9)]^2/(q*10^(10)*r*10^(-9))^2
 RH[q_, A_, Hi_] := (1/4)*p[q, A, Hi]^2*(2 + 1/(1 + p[q, A, Hi])^(0.5))
 RM[q_, A_, Hi_] := ((1 + p[q, A, Hi])^(0.5) - 1)/2
 Mz2[q_, dM_, r_] := ((dM/mu0)^2/(8*Pi)^3)*Vp[r]^2*FF[q, r];
 h2[q_, Hp_, r_] := ((Hp/mu0)^2/(8^3*Pi^3))*Vp[r]^2*FF[q, r];
 f[r_, c_, pp_, R_] := (1/(c*r*10^(-9)*pp))*Exp[-(Log[r*10^(-9)] - Log[R*10^(-9)])^2/(2*pp^2)]
 Sigma1[q_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, Hi_?NumericQ, dM_?NumericQ, 
 Hp_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, pp_?NumericQ, R_?NumericQ, BG_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[((Mz2[q, dM, r]*RM[q, A, Hi] + h2[q, Hp, r]*RH[q, A, Hi])*
 f[r, c, pp, R]), {r, 0, 100}, MaxRecursion -> 10] + BG
 model = Sigma1[xx, A, Hi, dM, Hp, c, pp, R, BG];
 result = FindFit[data, 
 model, {{A, 0.00000000000001}, {Hi, 20.6}, {dM, 0.05}, {Hp, 0.062}, {c, 0.005*10}, {pp, 0.78}, {R, 4}, {BG, 18}}, xx]
Plot[model /. result, {xx, 0, 0.3}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
ListPlot[data]
```

This Gives the fitting parameters as,

```
 {A -> 1.*10^-14, Hi -> 20.6, dM -> 0.05, Hp -> 0.062, c -> 0.05, pp -> 0.78, R -> 4., BG -> 8374.02}
```

Fitted Funtion:

[image]

Listplot of data.

[image]

This is totally Error Free!!,

but results are not matching, this is because of inappropriate choice of fitting parameters.

For the Desired Result:

Now you change your Guess parameter for proper fitting.

Even after doing that, you don't get the proper fitting, then search for better fitting function.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. If I want to put R and BG as constants and not fitting parameters  during the fit, the following line is correct ? ->  `model = Sigma1[xx, A, Hi, dM, Hp, c, pp, 4,18]`

Comment: @Bigprophete, Yes It will work.